# Capture global Audio Output in C++ (Portaudio)

Tags: c++, windows, audio, capture, portaudio

I have one question: Is there any possibillity to record the global Windows Output using Portaudio? I have read that you can change the input device to the actual output device but that's not working at all. So is there any other possibillity to record the output sound? 
I'd like to prefer using Portaudio but I'm not afraid to use other APIs. It should be a cross-platform API.

Best Regards,
Dennis

Comment: Did you find a solution how to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Counting on [Ross Bencina's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25474081/987846) ,

plus [an internet tip](https://discourse.libsdl.org/t/wasapi-loopback/23205/2): You need a PortAudio patch to enable WASAPI Loopback:

https://github.com/michaelni/audacity/blob/master/lib-src/portaudio-v19/wasapi-loopback.patch

Comment: 2022: The functionality got merged into official portaudio repository. https://github.com/PortAudio/portaudio/pull/672.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this can be done with [WASAPI Loopback Recording](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316551(v=vs.85).aspx)

PortAudio has a WASAPI back-end, so in principle you should be able to do it with PortAudio if you target a WASAPI PortAudio device. In practice I have never tried it so I can't guarantee that it will work.