# Recording audio from output device

Tags: c++, c, windows, audio

I'm trying to set up a program to record audio in windows, and I need to record from the output device. I'm looking into using the waveform audio interface, but I can't find a way to use the output device for recording.

Is there any way to make a hook in between the windows sound mixer and the physical output device?

Comment: Have a look at PortAudio: http://www.portaudio.com

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25291097/capture-global-audio-output-in-c-portaudio